# Owin Self Host Will Not Start

Tags: c#, owin, self-hosting

using VS2015 with admin permissions my host starts and I can receive requests using Nancyfx.

```
    IDisposable host = null;
    IDisposable HostStart()
    {
        try
        {
            return WebApp.Start<Startup1>("http://*:7002");
        }
        catch (HttpListenerException ex)
        {

            throw new  Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

When I make a setup project with the Visual Studio Extension and build and install and then run with admin privalages I don't get any exceptions but the server can not be found.I have turned off the firewall.I have now run out of ideas?

UPDATE: I am getting an exception

```
  An exception has been thrown by the taget of invocation.


  System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by          the  target of an invocation. ---> System.Exception: Object reference not set to   an instance of an object.
  at CabbyTechOffice.Startup1.Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]    arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,    Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags   invokeAttr,      Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
  at Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.<>c__DisplayClass12.   <MakeDelegate>b__b(IAppBuilder builder)
  at Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.<>c__DisplayClass1.  <LoadImplementation>b__0(IAppBuilder builder)
 at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.ResolveApp(StartContext   context)
 at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.Start(StartContext context)
 at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.DirectHostingStarter.Start(StartOptions    options)
 at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.HostingStarter.Start(StartOptions options)
 at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.StartImplementation(IServiceProvider  services, StartOptions options)
 at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start(StartOptions options)
 at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start[TStartup](StartOptions options)
 at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start[TStartup](String url)
 at CabbyTechOffice.MAIN.HostStart()
```

It seems the null ref is in the startup:

```
     public class MyBoot : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
    {
        protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
        {
            CabbyTechOfficeConfig fig = ConfigUI.GetCabbyTechConfig();
            if (fig == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("NO CONFIG");
            }
            ICabbytechOfficeDataAccess DB = null;
            try
            {
                DB = ConnDBCreater.CreateDB(fig.DatabaseComputerName + "\\" + fig.DatabaseInstanceName, "taxidb", fig.DbPassword, 8);
                IPEndPoint smsEP = null;
                SmsCommsMob sms = null;
                var comms = new ControlConnectAndSend(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, fig.DispatchFromPDAServerPort));
                try
                {
                    smsEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(fig.SmsIp), fig.SmsPort);
                    sms = new SmsCommsMob(smsEP);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
                StateInjector stateInjector = new StateInjector(DB, comms, sms);
                UdpBroadcasterJson.Send(new UDPCmd() { code = UDPCmd.commandsEnum.broadcastForDispatch }, stateInjector.UDPDispatchPort);

                try
                {
                    var comp = DB.CompaniesGet();
                    stateInjector.CompanyName = comp.company;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }

                try
                {
                    stateInjector.zones = DB.ZonesGet();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
                try
                {
                    var locLog = new PdaLocLog();
                    var locLogger = new PdaLocLogger(DB, locLog);
                    stateInjector.locLogger = locLogger;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
                container.Register<IStateInjector, StateInjector>(stateInjector);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }



        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Check if the port is not being used `C:\> netstat -bano | findstr "7002"`

Comment: I did check thanks no service on that port. I have to update question due to a exception that occurred but I hadn't realised.

Comment: Can you get to an inner exception?

Comment: Yep its a null reference exception.

Comment: If it's a null reference exceptions, nothing to do with permissions (I've deleted my answer). Which line is throwing? Nothing in the code you posted -looks- like it should throw a NRE

Comment: Jim W asked about an inner exception but it must be null.

Comment: Doesn't happen with VS tho.

Comment: Can you get the stack trace on the inner exception. Or sorry, are you saying that when you try to get the InnerException, that itself is null?  Also, please change to ex.ToString() instead of ex.Message because it will have more info.

Comment: I have dumped it to a text file and have updated the question

Comment: The null ref is coming from here: CabbyTechOffice.Startup1.Configuration(IAppBuilder app) can you share that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have chains of try/catches with empty catch blocks.

```
            try
            {
                var comp = DB.CompaniesGet();
                stateInjector.CompanyName = comp.company;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }

            try
            {
                stateInjector.zones = DB.ZonesGet();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            try
            {
                var locLog = new PdaLocLog();
                var locLogger = new PdaLocLogger(DB, locLog);
                stateInjector.locLogger = locLogger;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
```

this could leave stateInjector null which you then try to use.

You need to handle the catches in such a way that you can log any problems in those try/catches.  Presumably there's a problem in the environment where it's failing, but you don't know that because of the empty catches.

Answer (score 0):

There was problem in TinyIoc container in the NancyFx bootstrapper due to bad design in the exception handlers and a dependency was being injected null.